# Javascript updating object from string

Tags: javascript, object

I have this object `{country:{town:{company:{boss:{}}}}}` and this string `country.town.cityhouse.major`, I need to updatr the object from the string, but keeping the previous properties and data.

```
{
  country: {
    town: {
      company: {
        boss: {}
      },
      cityhouse: {
        major: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```js
function updateObj(object, path) {
            const newPath = path.split('.');
            let temp = {...object};

            for (let i = 0; i < newPath.length; i++) {
                let mid = temp[newPath[i]];
                if (mid) {
                    temp = mid;
                } else {
                    temp[newPath[i]] = {};
                }
            }

            return temp;
        }

        const obj = { country: { town: { company: { boss: {} }}}};
        const r = updateObj(obj, 'country.town.cityhouse.major');

        console.log(r);
```

but it responds:

```
{
  company: {
    boss: {}
  },
  cityhouse: {},
  major: {}
}
```

Any hint on this?

Comment: @James yes, that works. Post is an aswer to mark it as solution.

Comment: Why do you call it an update? isn't it  creating a new objet ?

Comment: A little late, this could be achieved using `set` from `lodash`.

Comment: In the future, please demonstrate that you've researched a solution to the best of your ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clean this up a little using [logical nullish assignment(??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) and a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

```js
function updateObj(object, path) {
  let result = { ...object };

  let temp = result;
  for (const k of path.split('.')) {
    temp = temp[k] ??= {};
  }

  return result;
}

const obj = { country: { town: { company: { boss: {} } } } };
const r = updateObj(obj, 'country.town.cityhouse.major');

console.log(r);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Recursive option

```js
function updateObj(object, path) {

  const result = { ...object };

  const [prop, ...pathArr] = path.split('.');

  result[prop] = pathArr.length 
    ? updateObj((result[prop] ??= {}), pathArr.join('.')) 
    : (result[prop] ??= {});

  return result;
}

const obj = { country: { town: { company: { boss: {} } } } };
const r = updateObj(obj, 'country.town.cityhouse.major');

console.log(r);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution, but, I would add the information that the logical nullish is a new feature  and some old browsers or browser versions doesn't support it. https://caniuse.com/?search=logical%20nullish

Comment: Agreed. Could be replaced with an OR shortcircuit `temp = temp[k] || (temp[k] = {});`, or a more verbose ternary `temp = temp[k] !== undefined ? temp[k] : (temp[k] = {});`

Answer (score 2):

This code would normally be written recursively, so you need to have a variable to hold the current scope (the path you walked on through the object) to do the job, and so i created the variable called `scope` to do that job.

```js
function updateObj(object, path) {
    const newPath = path.split('.');
    let temp = {...object};
    let scope = temp;
    for (let i = 0; i < newPath.length; i++) {
        let cur = scope[newPath[i]];
        if (!cur) {
            scope = scope[newPath[i]] = {};
        } else {
            scope = cur;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

const obj = { country: { town: { company: { boss: {} }}}};
const r = updateObj(obj, 'country.town.cityhouse.major');

console.log(r);
```

This is a recursive implementation, but since it requires copying the object and passing it to the next recursive call it's not an efficient one, If i find a better more efficient implementation, I'll update this.

```js
function updateObjRec(object, path, depth = 0) {
    // base case
    // if depth is equal to path length then it's over
    if (depth === path.length) {
        return {};
    }

    const cur = path[depth];
    const scope = object[cur];

    // here we have 2 cases
    // current field already exists
    update = {};
    if (scope) {
        update = updateObjRec({ ...scope}, path, depth + 1);
    } else {
        update = updateObjRec({}, path, depth + 1);
    }

    // merge with given object
    object[cur] = update;

    return object
}

const obj = { country: { town: { company: { boss: {} }}}};
const r = updateObjRec(obj, 'country.town.cityhouse.major'.split('.'));

console.log(r);
```

**Update**
The recursive code can be rewritten this way to be more efficient

```js
function updateObj(obj, path) {
    const temp = { ...obj };
    const p = path.split('.');

    const updateRec = (scope, depth = 0) => {
        // base case
        if (depth === p.length) return;

        const cur = p[depth];
        if (!scope[cur]) {
          scope[cur] = {};
        }
        updateRec(scope[cur], depth + 1);
    }

    updateRec(temp);

    return temp;
}

const obj = { country: { town: { company: { boss: {} }}}};
const r = updateObj(obj, 'country.town.cityhouse.major');

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Might be worth adding the recursive "normal" that you've alluded to as well.

Comment: Just added it, although not very efficient, recursive code is usually easier to implement but not as efficient as iterative code, I'll update it once I find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't ideal, but it's a start.
Basically, you're returning temp, which is the lowest layer. you want to return the root.
Also when you can't find the next layer, you were creating it, but you weren't updating temp.

```js
function updateObj(object, path) {
    const newPath = path.split('.');
    let temp = {...object};
    const result = temp; // need to return this

    for (let i = 0; i < newPath.length; i++) {
        let mid = temp[newPath[i]];
        if (mid) {
            temp = mid;
        } else {
            temp[newPath[i]] = {};
            temp = temp[newPath[i]] // need this
        }
    }

    return result;
}

const obj = { country: { town: { company: { boss: {} }}}};
const r = updateObj(obj, 'country.town.cityhouse.major');

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to achieve

```js
const obj = {
  country: {
    town: {
      company: { boss: {} },
    },
  },
};

obj.country.town.cityhouse = {
  major: {},
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: not that simple, the updates must be as string